# Comparing list values and storing new ones in a separate list

Tags: python, list

```
import csv

with open("DADSA RESIT CWK JULY 2018.csv", newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    database = list(r)

del database[0]
names = []
names.append([])

def fillnames(d, n):
    for j in n:
        for i in d:
            if d[i][0] == n[j][0] and d[i][1] == n[j][1]:
                n[i][2] = n[i][2]+1
            else:
                names.append([d[i][0], d[i][1], 0])

fillnames(database, names)

for i in names:
    print(i)
```

The code I have here is me scanning in a csv file into a list. I then want to count how many entries share the same name, by scanning each new name into a separate list, then incrementing the number found every time I find a new one. Every time I run this code it returns "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list."

Comment: can you provide some example lines? like it is on the csv file.

Comment: What do you mean? If you mean an example of what should appear in the names list, it should read ["surname" "first name", number of times found in list (e.g. 2)] in that order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need `database`:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open("DADSA RESIT CWK JULY 2018.csv", newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader) # discard headers
    name_counts = Counter((row[0], row[1]) for row in reader)
```

If you do need `database`:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open("DADSA RESIT CWK JULY 2018.csv", newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader) # discard headers
    database = list(reader)
name_counts = Counter((row[0], row[1]) for row in database)
```

The root error in your original code is this:

```
for i in d:
    if d[i] ...
```

When you do `for item in somelist` in Python `item` is not an index, it's the actual item.  In the case of `for i in d`, `d` is a list of lists--so `i` is one of the sublists (one of the rows).  You should now see why Python would be confused by `d[i]` and give "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list."

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!